# Printing array of sums returned from function doesn't print the sums

Tags: java, arrays

The task is to return the sum of each row of a 2D array in a 1D array.

#### Example

```
int[][] values = {  
                     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, 
                     {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}, {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}, 
                     {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}
                 };
```

I want to print: 
`Row sums: 15 15 15 15 15`

#### Code

```
public int[]allRowSums()
    {
        int rowSum = 0;
        int current = 0;
        int[]a = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            a = new int[values[i].length];
            for(int j = 0; j < values[current].length; j++)
            {
                rowSum = values[current][j];
                a[i] += rowSum;
            }
            rowSum = 0;
            current++;            
        }
        return a;        
    }
```

when I call this method I get: 
`Row sums: [I@15db9742`

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));` instead

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate because there were other issues in the code as well. Just printing out the array wouldn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code fix**

The current implementation returns somehow `0, 0, 0, 0, 15` if printed correctly converting the array to String first:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

It happens because you always refresh all the values in the first (outer) for-loop. Do the following

```
int rowSum = 0;
int current = 0;
int[] a = new int[values.length];                   // proper initialization to avoid NPE
for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
                                                    // this line removed
    for (int j=0; j<values[current].length; j++) {
        rowSum = values[current][j];
        a[i] += rowSum;
    }
    rowSum = 0;
    current++;
}
return a;
```

Now the code works correctly and will contain `15, 15, 15, 15, 15` on your sample.

**Better solution**

Stream API is suitable for this use case. A proper combination of collector [`Collectors::summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and mapping does the trick

```
int[] array = Arrays.stream(values)
                    .map(i -> Arrays.stream(i)
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(Collectors.summingInt(j -> j)))
                    .mapToInt(i -> i)
                    .toArray();
```

Printing this `array` to ex. a console will produce the very same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the *reference* to the array and not the sum. Also in each iteration you are creating a new array, due to which the previous values are lost.

Simpy move the initialization outside the loop:

```
public static int[] allRowSums() {
    int rowSum = 0;
    int current = 0;
    int[] a = new int[values.length];        // observe this change (only 1 change made)
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[current].length; j++) {
            rowSum = values[current][j];
            a[i] += rowSum;
        }
        rowSum = 0;
        current++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

And as mentioned in the comments, you are *printing* the reference of the array, use `Arrays.toString()` to print out the array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allRowSums()));
```

Comment: This is my point, how can I return the array and not the reference?

Comment: Returning the reference to the array is fine, but when you try to print it out what you get is in fact the *memory address* of the reference. Either use Arrays.toString or you can *manually* iterate over the array and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the result of the sum, you should use a loop to iterate all the elements of the array.

Try something like this

```
for(int intVar :  a)
    System.out.println(intVar);
```